# How to implement black and white filter to a document

Tags: javascript, image-processing, fabricjs

How can I use fabricjs or any other JavaScript library to apply black and white filter to a document to get the following results?

input image:
[image: input image]

expected result:
[image: expected result]

input image:
[image: input image]

expected result:
[image: expected result]

Comment: Please elaborate your question in more detail and with some initial codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:http://jsfiddle.net/qasLmxvh/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$('.select_image').change(function (e) {
        loadImage(e.target.files[0]);
    });
    is_grayscale = true;
function loadImage(src) {

    if (!src.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        console.log("The dropped file is not an image: ", src.type);
        return;
    }

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        let imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = e.target.result;
        imgObj.onload = function () {
        let scale = 300 / Math.max(imgObj.naturalWidth, imgObj.naturalHeight);
            let img = new fabric.Image(imgObj, {
                left: 10,
                top: 10,
                scaleX: scale,
                scaleY: scale
            });
            canvas.add(img);
               toGrey();
               img.diry=1;
            canvas.renderAll();
            
            
        };
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(src);
}
function toGrey() {
    let grayscale = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
    canvas.getObjects().forEach(function (t) {
      if (t.hasOwnProperty('filters')) {
        if (is_grayscale) {
          t.filters.push(grayscale);
        } else {
          t.filters.length = 0;
        }
        t.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      } else if (t.hasOwnProperty('fill')) {
        let color_sum = t.fill
        .match(/\d+,\d+,\d+/)[0]
        .split(',')
        .map((i) => parseInt(i))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

        let gray = color_sum / 3;

        t.setColor(to_rgba({r: gray, g: gray, b: gray, a: 1}));
      }
    });
    applyFilter(1, new f.Contrast({
      contrast: 255
    }));
    canvas.renderAll();
}
function applyFilter(index, filter) {
  var obj = canvas.getObjects()[0];
  obj.filters[index] = filter;
  obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}

var f = fabric.Image.filters;

document.getElementById("input").onchange = function() {
  applyFilter(1, new f.Contrast({
    contrast: parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value,10)
  }));
};
```

Basically I applied a grayscale effect and after this a contrast effect.
[image]

Comment: thanks @Marius Turcu ,but it does not give the required result with all images , for example it does not give good result with images with strong illumination gradient or shadows, how can we apply adaptive threshold in fabricjs to give the required result with all images.this is a link for the result [https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq6mv.png]

Comment: You can remove/add shadow based on the current image and its other values of properties.

Comment: @khajaamin, Could you explain how to do it?